# How to get the soap request going out with the call using wsdl c#?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, xml-serialization

Very new to this. I am using a wsdl. Generating the web reference and .net builds the classes in references.cs. Now is there any way I can get the soap request going out though any c# methods in my code?

Getting at `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize` error in prod but absolutely working fine in UAT. No body has no clue on why? Can someone pls provide insights on getting the soap request going out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tool fiddler to track the request and responce

Comment: This fiddler has been a life saver more than once:) Thanks